# Testing/mocking file IO in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a simple test:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  testWidgets(
    'Simple empty test',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      print("1");
      await Directory('/tmp').exists();
      print("2");
      await tester.pumpWidget(Container());
    },
  );
}
```

It freezes after printing `1`. I know that Flutter runs test in fake-async zones and I know that I am required to run code with real IO with runAsync.

However, is it also possible somehow to inject a mock IO filesystem and run the tests without runAsync?

Answer (score 11):

After doing some research I found the [`file`](https://pub.dev/packages/file) package from the google team which allows developers to use the `LocalFileSystem` (basically `dart:io`), a `MemoryFileSystem` or a custom `FileSystem`.

Especially the  `MemoryFileSystem` or even the  custom `FileSystem` could come in handy for unit and widget tests since these can be used so no files are created on the hard drive. Therefore, it is a lot easier to create and cleanup the `FileSystem` after a test has run.

The drawback of this approach is that one has to inject the `FileSystem` into every module requiring access to *Files*, *Directories*, etc.

**Example**

```
import 'package:file/file.dart';

class DirectoryOperator {
  final FileSystem fileSystem;

  // Inject implementation of the FileSystem
  DirectoryOperator({required this.fileSystem});

  Future<void> methodOperatingOnFileSystem(String path) async {
    Directory directory = fileSystem.directory(path);
    await directory.create(recursive: true);
  }
}
```

**Test code**

```
import 'package:file/file.dart';
import 'package:file/memory.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

main() {
  test('$DirectoryOperator creates directory on path', () async {
    FileSystem fileSystem = MemoryFileSystem();
    var systemUnderTest = DirectoryOperator(fileSystem: fileSystem);
    String testPath = 'Path/to/dir';
    await systemUnderTest.methodOperatingOnFileSystem(testPath);

    bool doesDirectoryExist = await fileSystem.directory(testPath).exists();
    expect(
      doesDirectoryExist,
      isTrue,
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I/O operations may be mocked using [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) and [`IOOverrides`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/IOOverrides-class.html):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

import 'test.mocks.dart';

class TestFile extends MockFile {
  final String _path;
  TestFile(this._path) {
    when(readAsStringSync()).thenReturn('(string from $_path)');
  }
}

@GenerateMocks([File])
void main() {
  test('I/O overrides', () {
    IOOverrides.runZoned(() {
      expect(File('path/to/a').readAsStringSync(), '(string from path/to/a)');
      expect(File('path/to/b').readAsStringSync(), '(string from path/to/b)');
    }, createFile: (String path) => TestFile(path));
  });
}
```

The above example uses `IOOverrides` to hook into the creation of `File` objects, and return a mock `File`-like object.